# gradle build consistently fails at download of random plugin

Tags: gradle, plugins, build.gradle

For two days now, I have the problem, that my gradle builds fail (pretty consistently, today only one in 15 succeeded) when downloading the gradle plugins. The plugin, thats download fails, seems random. Sometimes I cannot download the plugin afterwards "by hand", other times I can...

I had the same issue some time ago already (and maybe once more), but then "it fixed itself" after some hours (I think I tried stuff until lunch and afterwards everything was back to normal).

Here's the failing part of my log:

```
10:47:10 Download https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/jcraft/jzlib/1.1.2/jzlib-1.1.2.jar
10:47:10 Download https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/apache/ant/ant-antlr/1.8.4/ant-antlr-1.8.4.jar
10:47:10 Download https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/sonarsource/scanner/gradle/sonarqube-gradle-plugin/2.6.2/sonarqube-gradle-plugin-2.6.2.jar
10:47:10 Download https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/apache/ant/ant/1.8.4/ant-1.8.4.jar

10:47:43 
10:47:43 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
10:47:43 
10:47:43 * What went wrong:
10:47:43 A problem occurred configuring root project 'root'.
10:47:43 > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
10:47:43    > Could not download sequence-library.jar (de.regnis.q.sequence:sequence-library:1.0.3)
10:47:43       > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/de/regnis/q/sequence/sequence-library/1.0.3/sequence-library-1.0.3.jar'.
10:47:43          > Could not GET 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/de/regnis/q/sequence/sequence-library/1.0.3/sequence-library-1.0.3.jar'.
10:47:43             > Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/159.122.18.156] failed: connect timed out
```

I already found this github issue: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/3326

There they argued, that it could have to do something with the feature "Avoid checking other repositories when dependency resolution in one repository fails" ( https://docs.gradle.org/4.3/release-notes.html#avoid-checking-other-repositories-when-dependency-resolution-in-one-repository-fails ), that was introduced in Gradle 4.3. In fact I sometimes get an `403 "resource not found"` (not sure about the exact wording here) when I try to manully download a plugin from `repo.jfrog.org`.

I also already read about "sitting behind a proxy" thing. That might be the case (I have to check with our admins), but I think the fact, that in some rare cases the build succeeds, is an argument against it, right?

If there is any more info I can help with, please ask :)

Any help is appreciated, because this is a really annoying state right now. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your exact `gradle` version ?

Comment: Have 4.6 but tried it with 4.7 and 4.2.1 as well.

Comment: Could you share your `repositories` setup ?

Comment: I have just mavenLocal and our internal artifactory configured there. But I also tried to add jcenter there (above and below).In the buildscript part I have nothing configured (we're currently planning on having our internal artifactory proxying plugins.gradle.org/m2, but we do not have it yet).

Comment: This new gradle behaviour seems to be irreversible so you have to deal with it. This guy ( https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/3299#issuecomment-340065768 ) advices to order the repositories in a way so that the weakest is checked in last position

Comment: But I haven't configured any repository for my plugins.. Or is it just using the same as for the other dependencies? I thought it makes a difference, if it is in the `buildscript {...}` part of the `build.gradle`. I also tried using 4.2.1 again, and it also fails.

Comment: I found this docu part for custom plugin repositories: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:custom_plugin_repositories . So I assume, the `repositories {...}` part of my `build.gradle` should have absolutely no effect on the download/resolution of plugins, right?

Comment: If you have the issue with gradle 4.2.1, I think it's unrelated with the dependency resolution behaviour introduced in gradle 4.3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169444/discussion-between-razr-and-toyonos).

Comment: My build recently started failing just like this, random dependency off of jcenter each time. This only happened when using the `--refresh-dependencies` flag on my build command. It seems jcenter thinks we were DDOSing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly I cannot really give a solution for the problem we encountered. It might be a problem or a new configuration at the jcenter-side, it might have to do something with the proxy thing.

We fixed it by proxying everything through our internal repos and backup the artifacts there, what probably everyone should do who has the infrastructure, bc this really removes traffic from the official repos.